# NLTK index of a word with mulitiple occurences

Tags: python, indexing, nltk

I'm trying to use python to find the index of the word 'the' in the following text

`sent3 = ['In', 'the', 'beginning', 'God', 'created', 'the', 'heaven', 'and', 'the', 'earth', '.']`

If I do `sent3.index('the')` I get `1`, which is the index of the first occurrence of the word. What I'm not sure on is how to find the indexes of the other times "the" appears. Does anyone know how I could go about doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[i for i, item in enumerate(sent3) if item == wanted_item]
```

Demo:

```
>>> sent3 = ['In', 'the', 'beginning', 'God', 'created', 'the', 'heaven', 'and', 'the', 'earth', '.']
>>> [i for i, item in enumerate(sent3) if item == 'the']
[1, 5, 8]
```

[`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#enumerate) just constructs a `list` of tuples from an iterable, consisting of their values and their corresponding indices. We can use this to check if the value is what we want, and if so pull the index from it.

Comment: @Downvoter If you tell me what was not helpful or wrong about my answer to deserve a down-vote, I am able to improve it. What good does it do simply down-voting?

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> sent3 = ['In', 'the', 'beginning', 'God', 'created', 'the', 'heaven', 'and', 'the', 'earth', '.']
>>> idx = defaultdict(list)
>>> for i,j in enumerate(sent3):
...     idx[j].append(i)
... 
>>> idx['the']
[1, 5, 8]
```